# Redis queue to handle asynchronous task in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, rabbitmq, sidekiq, amazon-sqs

I'm building a scalable Rails application. When a user takes an action on the application, I'm responding with status `200` and then push some analytics data asynchronously to DynamoDB based on user action.

One way to do this is pushing job in sidekiq queue. Is there any other way to do the same? Is using SQS/RabbitMQ is more elegant way to do this, as I might have to do 2-3 operations (send notifications, save data analytics etc)?

Thanks,

**EDIT:**
Redis + Sidekiq does the work. Here, Redis works as a message queue and Sidekiq processes those message in the background. I'm curious to know, what are the use cases and benefits of selecting an explicit broker(such as RabbitMQ, SQS, Redis PubSub) over Redis + Sidekiq?

Answer (score -2):

You are right, SQS/RabbitMQ is the better option. But there is more..

I did some research and found [this](http://www.cloudhack.in/2016/02/29/apache-kafka-vs-rabbitmq/).

According to this, **kafka is better in terms of performance**. It also provides a stream data processing framework [kafka-streams](http://docs.confluent.io/3.0.0/streams/)(in case you want to do small transformations on the data before pushing to DynamoDB).